# How to generate random chars and insert with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Duplicate:**
>   [Inserting random characters to MYSQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498310/inserting-random-characters-to-mysql-database)

How can I generate 100 records with 5 random characters and insert into the database with a query.

I want to insert into this table:

```
codes
  id (auto-increment)
  codes
```

Answer (score 18):

Try this one -

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  CHAR( FLOOR(65 + (RAND() * 25))),
  CHAR( FLOOR(65 + (RAND() * 25))),
  CHAR( FLOOR(65 + (RAND() * 25))),
  CHAR( FLOOR(65 + (RAND() * 25))),
  CHAR( FLOOR(65 + (RAND() * 25)))
  ) random_string;
```

This query generates ASCII codes from 'A' to 'Z' and generates a random string from them.
I cannot say that this way is elegant, but it works;-)

Answer (score 8):

```
INSERT INTO codes_tbl (codes) VALUES (SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 5));
```

That should take care of it.

Comment: Except that `md5` gives you a string that only includes hex digits so the codes will be quite limited.

Comment: hello, i cannot run the code. got an error. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: There is an issue with the parentheses:`INSERT INTO codes_tbl (codes) VALUES (SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 5));`

Answer (score 0):

In MySql U Can Do It Like This

```
insert into table ( SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 10) , field2 , field3) , ( SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 10) , field2 , field3) , .........
```

If You Want to Do it With Php. U Can [Check This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307486/short-unique-id-in-php/307773#307773)

Further You can Check The Following Questions Already asked at Stackoverflow

[1.  Random Number- MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498310/inserting-random-characters-to-mysql-database)

[2.  Mysql insert random unique 8 chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009171/mysql-insert-random-unique-8-chars)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this out?:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertOneHundredRandomCodes` ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE ctr INT DEFAULT 0;
    hundred_loop:LOOP
        SET ctr = ctr + 1; -- increment
        -- insert command here
        INSERT INTO codes (codes)
        SELECT SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 5) AS codes;
        IF ctr = 100 THEN -- check if we should stop
            LEAVE hundred_loop;
        END IF;
    END LOOP hundred_loop;
END//
```

Create that procedure then run this command:

```
CALL InsertOneHundredRandomCodes();
```

It should insert into `codes` 100 random values for the `codes` value.